# Convert a .flv stream to mp4 without burdening the server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

with flask, I have the client download a live streaming .flv, the problem is that the client receives a .flv file, when I would like it to receive an .mp4. Renaming the file is not enough, you really have to convert it in real time without burdening the server, because there may be more than one download going on.

I would like to point out, that the file should not be downloaded to the server.

This is the code with which I have the file downloaded:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    try:
        url = request.args.get('url')
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        content_type = r.headers['Content-Type']

        def generate():
            try:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        yield chunk
            finally:
                r.close()
                return r
            
        response = Response(generate(), mimetype=content_type)
        # Here I can rename it to .mp4, but it still remains a flv
        response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=f'{filename}.flv')
        return response
    except:
       pass
```